# Problem in moving Clash Royale account from android to iOS

Tags: clash-royale

I have installed the latest version of Clash Royale on both my devices (the old device and the new one which is iOS device).

Also both my devices are connected to a stable WiFi and my android is connected to Google Play & Google Play Games. My iOS device is connected to Game Center too.

I want to move my Clash Royale from my old Android device to my new iPhone I tried to follow the steps mentioned in the link below:

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-connect-my-Clash-Royale-on-Android-to-my-Clash-Royale-on-Ipad

But unfortunately both of my devices do not show the **Link device** button.

My Settings section looks like below:

[image: My Clash Royale Settings]

But the link says that it should look like this:

[image: The settings page as the links says]

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the link you are following is a bit outdated, and I'm not sure that Supercell supports the link feature anymore. The best solution would be to use a common email and link the devices using [Supercell ID](https://forum.supercell.com/showthread.php/1691777-One-Only-Supercell-ID-Thread).

Comment: Thanks, it fixed my problem. I just created a Supercell ID in my old device and logged in inside my new device and everything was fixed.

Comment: Glad to know it worked. Good luck in CR!